# Paperclip for Rails: Can I access the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Let's say I have a model called Theme, which has several attributes setting interface colors. Theme also has a Paperclip attachment, which is a user-generated CSS template. I want to set up a processor to generate a final CSS file, inserting the interface colors into the user-generated template. To do this, I need to access the model data from within the processor. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The processor has an accessor called `attachment` this points back to the instance of Paperclip::Attachment. The attachment in turn has an accessor `instance` which points to the instance of the original model. So all you should have to do from the processor is call `attachment.instance` to get the original model.